# Does Transient Dependency Injection of an ServiceBus Azure Function will be injected for every run?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function that listens for a ServiceBus and one of the roles of the process is to generate some GUIDs.

I can't share my code but it look something like this:

```
public class ServiceBusListenerFunction
{
    private readonly IProcessService _processService;

    public ServiceBusListenerFunction(IProcessService processService)
    {
        _processService = processService;
    }

    [FunctionName("MyServiceBusFunction")]
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("my-queue")] string message)
    {
        await _processService.Run(message);
    }
}
```

I injected IProcessService as Transient in an atempt to inject for every Run call of my function.

My concern are all concurrent calls, even for a very little chance, generate duplicate GUID.

There is a way to manually inject IProccessService and all its dependencies for every call?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think you should be worrying about generating duplicate GUIDs.  You have a better chance of winning the lottery 1000 times (assuming your GUID generation algorithm is sound).

Comment: You can check if it creates a new instance every time by putting a breakpoint in the service constructor and see if it gets called each time.

Comment: If you call _processService.GetHashCode() and log that value in constructor. If it's different each time then it is different instance of it is same it is singleton.